# Qt-Qml: Binding checkbox to QAbstractListModel

Tags: c++, qt, data-binding, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I am facing a problem while developing my program. I have a `QAbstractListModel` which contain a `boole` property, and I want to be able to pass that value to my QML file containing a `CheckBox`.

I found [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860270/binding-checkbox-checked-property-with-a-c-object-q-property) covering the same problem. I am facing the exact same problem but the question and answer cover the case where the property is sent to the qml through a `Q_PROPERTY` whereas I use a `QAbstractListmodel`. I have overridden the `setData()`, `data()` and `flags()` methods and all works fine but I have a button that check/uncheck all my `CheckBox`es and if the user directly check one of them that one will not be editable through my check/uncheck button.

So basically, I want to know how to set up a bi-directional binding using a `QAbstractListModel` instead of a `Q_PROPERTY`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for bothering you. I just found out the answer using my very little brain for more than 5 minutes.

I just needed to use the `dataChanged` signal in order to be able to connect correctly my model to the view.

```
 CheckBox {
        id: myCheck
        onClicked: user.status = checked
        Component.onCompleted: checked = user.status
        Connections {
            target: user
            onDataChanged: myCheck.checked = user.status
        }
    }
```

Didn't know we could pass an existing signal directly to QML just putting `on` in front on the signal's name.

Comment: *Any* property, property as a corresponding changing handler, i.e. if you define a property `myProp` you can declare an handler `onMyProp` with the first letter uppercase. Same goes for signals. If the answer solved your problem just accept this as the correct answer, please.

Comment: To add to @BaCaRoZzo's comment, any custom-defined property must begin with a small letter.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo it's `onMyPropChanged`

Comment: Lol...obviously it is. Just lost it. Thanks to pointint it out. :) So it's `name` (first letter lowercase) for the signal/property and `onNameChanged` (first letter of property/signal uppercase) for the corresponding handler.